# Netty Framework: UDP sending of mass data

Tags: udp, netty

Using Netty 3.5.3 I'm implementing a UDP server which has to send continuously small data packets without any request-response communication. Anywhere in a forum I found the hint the best hook to do that is to override the channelBound method of SimpleChannelHandler.

```
private static class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    private TargetDataReader dataReader = new TargetDataReader();

    private InetSocketAddress remoteAddress;

    private long sleep;

    /**
     * @param host
     * @param port
     */
    public MyHandler(String host, int port, long sleep) {
        super();
        this.remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }

    /*
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void channelBound(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();

        int cnt = 0;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        byte[] targetData;
        while ((targetData = dataReader.nextData()) != null) {

            ChannelBuffer tdBuf = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(targetData);

            ++cnt;
            ChannelFuture cf = ch.write(tdBuf, this.remoteAddress);
            cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                @Override
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Server - record sent "
                            + (future.isSuccess() ? "successfully" : "failed"));
                }
            });
            cf.await(30);

            if (sleep > 0)
                Thread.sleep(sleep);

            System.out.println("Server - written records " + cnt);
        }

        long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Server - duration=" + duration + ", cnt=" + cnt + ", records/sec="
                + String.format("%f", ((double) cnt) / duration * 1000));
    }
```

At the first glance it seemed to work. But looking deeper I realized that the receiving client got about 50% of the data packets only. Furthermore, and I think that is the actual problem, the server doesn't really send the data packets when calling **ChannelFuture cf = ch.write(tdBuf, this.remoteAddress);** but not until the channelBound method was finished and than with one stroke. Unfortunately I have no idea and would be appreciative to get a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from `channelBound` as quickly as possible as you are holding up Netty's I/O threads by running all of your code there.

You should use an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) (or something equivalent in the Netty library, if it exists) to execute your long running code (in this case, your `dataReader` loop) so that one of Netty's threads is not blocking waiting for your code to finish.